# Android Studio Emulator (Ubuntu)-Process Finished with the exit code 0

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, android-emulator

When I am running my emulator using android studio it shows process finished with exit code 0 and the emulator is not working.Kindly anyone help me to sort out this problem.